# Open Password Protected .mdb file

Tags: c#, ms-access, database-connection

Compiler error on the dd.TableDefs...what do I alter so this code will function properly?  It looksl ike the issue comes from me Trying to use DAO & Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB but I do not know how to fix.  Exact error is

```
Error   27  Use of unassigned local variable 'dd'   


DAO.Database dd;
DAO.TableDef tdf1;
DAO.DBEngine db = new DAO.DBEngine();
string newName = "Just_Auto_Linked_In";
string SQLName = "Just_Auto_Linked_In";
string oledbConnectString =
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data   Source=C:\\Databases\\Testing.mdb;" +
"Jet OLEDB:Database Password=foxtrotcharliealpha;";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(oledbConnectString))
{
connection.Open();
string[] tableNames = new string[1] { "Magnus", };
for (int q = tableNames.GetLowerBound(0); q <= tableNames.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
{
    foreach (DAO.TableDef tabledef in dd.TableDefs)
    {
        string viewName = tableNames[q];
        if (tabledef.Name == viewName) { found = true; }
        try { if (found) { dd.TableDefs.Delete(viewName); } }
        catch { }
    }
}
tdf1 = dd.CreateTableDef(newName);
tdf1.Connect = cs1;
tdf1.SourceTableName = SQLName;
dd.TableDefs.Append(tdf1);
}
```

EDIT #1
This will open a db w/o a password, but if I am unable to pass a the password to the DAO open.

```
DAO.Database dd;
DAO.DBEngine db = new DAO.DBEngine();
string TestDB = "C:\\Databases\\Testing.mdb;" ";
dd = db.OpenDatabase(TestDB);
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: @bokibeg of course I would leave out the pertinent info.  Updated original post.

Comment: Ok I see the problem, you are calling `dd` and it's declared as `DAO.Database dd` but it's not **assigned** anywhere, it's `null`. Unfortunately it's been a very long time since I used DAO so I'm not sure how DAO Databases are even instantiated.

Comment: @bokibeg after hours of googling, I see how to use DAO to open a database, but not to open one with a password, so I am almost still in the same predicament.

Answer (score 0):

This is VBA, but you should be able to port it over to C# relatively easy.

```
Sub OpenPwdProtectedDB()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
Set ws = DBEngine.WorkSpaces(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase("H:\Database\database.mdb", False, False, "MS Access;PWD=password")
'Do what you want to here
'
'
'
'
db.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: The line of code that reads 'Set ws = DBEngine.Workspace(0)' what is the C# equivelant of that?  I can't seem to figure out that 1 piece.